# What to do when I have to use 'isSomething' as name of a Boolean variable?

Tags: java, boolean, naming-conventions, getter

The question itself is I have to use 'is' as a name of a Boolean variable for reasons, and I don't know if it's better to find a way to change it's name, or that's not that big problem to use 'isSomething' for the variable and 'isSomething()' for the getter?

Comment: No problem, I even think that eclipse auto GET/SET generator do that.

Comment: Variable and method name can be the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in having a field `private boolean isSomething;` and a getter

```
public boolean isSomething() {
    return isSomething;
}
```